# What is the name of This Surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

What is the name of this surface? [image]

And here is the Parametric equation:

```
f = {u, Sin[v]*(u^3 + 2 u^2 - 2 u + 2)/5, Cos[v]*(u^3 + 2 u^2 - 2 u + 2)/5};
```

Comment: Huh, flowerpot? (Just kiddin')

Comment: I don't know that it has a specific name, but it's a surface of revolution generated by the graph of a cubic polynomial.

Comment: could be dubbed cubicpot?

Comment: A flowerpot is actually quite good.